How can I dynamically change the theme of an android splash screen?
I have an android app whith a StartupActivity that serves as a splash screen while preparing the app. I use a special splash theme for that activity:
<activity
    android:name=".activity.StartupActivity"
    [...]
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
    [...]
</activity>

Works fine, as explained in the documentation that splash screen is shown when the app cold starts until the first "real" activity is started. That is a dashboard activity that uses the normal app theme defined for all activities:
<application
    android:name=".SomeApp"
    [...]
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    [...]
>

I am looking for a way to dynamically change that splash theme inside the StartupActivity. With any usual activity I can use setTheme(...) inside the activities onCreate(...) method before the call to super.onCreate(...). That changes the theme before the activity starts to render itself which is perfect.
That does not work for the splash screen however. The theme does get applied, but far too late: the theme is only changed a while after the initial splash screen has been shown. I think that is due to that splash screen getting handled in a special way by android: it is initialized before that StartupActivity is launched which is the whole point of a splash screen. Which would explain why changing the theme dynamically works, but only too late.
Is there a way to achieve what I had in mind?
Is it possible to change the splash screen's theme dynamically from within the application, so that the change get's applied initially?
